# Javascript 'window.location.href' works only first time on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, php, mobile

I have a script that determines whether a user has accessed a particular site (e.g. test-abc.com) on a PC or mobile device.

If the site is accessed from a mobile device, the script should redirect the user to the mobile app (e.g. Test ABC App). However, it only successfully redirects the user the first time.
On attempting to load the site on the mobile device the second time, the script no longer redirects.

How can I force a redirect, or what other methods can I use to make the mobile device open the app instead?
Please do not give suggestions like 'just clear the cache' because we can't make customers do that.

```
if ( wpmd_is_notdevice() ) { // User loaded website on desktop
    // Do something
} else { // Redirect to app
    ?>
    <script>
        window.location.href = 'https://app.abc-test.com';
    </script>
    <?php
    exit();
}
```

Comment: How can we fix your code if you don't share it. [mcve]

Comment: Added the PHP script, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try versioning the script so it doesn't get cached. Place your JavaScript function in an external file, then add a version number to that file via php.

My PHP is not great so you'll probaly need to edit a bit but you'll get the gist of the idea

```
//scripts.js

function redirect() {
 window.location.href = 'https://app.abc-test.com';
}

redirect();
```

Then in the HTML

```
if ( wpmd_is_notdevice() ) { // User loaded website on desktop
    // Do something
} else { // Redirect to app
  ?>

    // generate random number in php and insert as version number
    $versionNumber = rand(10,100);
    $versionNumber = (string)$versionNumber;
    $script = "<script src='/scripts.js?v='" . $versionNumber ."'></script>"

    echo $script;
  <?php
  exit();
}
```